# request.form is null

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, asp.net, mvc

Создаю веб сервер на который будут отправляться post запросы от других серверов, создал контроллер

```
public string rec()
{
  var value = "";
  for (int i = 0; i < keys.Length; i++)
  {
  value = value + Request.Form[keys[i]] + "  |  ";
  }
  // сохраняю данный "value" в  базу
  return "1";
}
```

при просмотре данных в базе, получаю null.
Пробовал изменить код контроллера на следующий:

```
public string rec(string type)
{
  var value = "";
  for (int i = 0; i < keys.Length; i++)
  {
  value = value + Request.Form[keys[i]] + "  |  ";
  }
  value += type
  // сохраняю данный "value" в  базу
  return "1";
}
```

и на выходе получаю в базе только сохранённый "type".
это происходит только на хостинге, на локалке всё нормально.
заранее прописать входные пост переменные в контроллер невозможно, т.к. не известно их кол-во и имена, но "type" присутствует всегда. сохранение в базу точно работает, ответ от серверов на мой сервер точно приходит, ответ всегда корректный.
Вопросы:
 1. можно ли каким то другим путём получить post данные?
 2. как устранить данную ошибку?

Answer (score 0):

1)Плохо и неправильно писать так `return "1";`, т.к. это скрывает проблему, нужно делать так `return value;` и потом это значение проверять в вызывающей части кода.

2) Раз у вас в измененном методе сохраняется только `type` значит нужно проверять отладкой почему не работает `Request.Form[keys[i]]`.

Это всё, что можно сказать глядя на ваш код.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка была в том что данные лежат в теле запроса, которые я вытаскиваю с помощью

```
byte[] buf = this.Request.BinaryRead(this.Request.ContentLength);
            string t = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buf);
```